# Count in pivot table based on Date period

Tags: mysql, database, pivot

I am trying to create a pivot table for a column booking status for monthly basis

this is my table and query

```
select bkg.status,
       bkg.StartDate 
from tbl_booking bkg 
where bkg.StartDate between '2018-09-17' and '2018-10-17'  
order by bkg.StartDate
```

I want to be in a format like

```
Date Period     sep | Oct | Nov 

Status 1         10 | 20  |30
Status 2         40 | 50  |60
```

I tried the following query

```
SELECT bkg.StartDate ,bkg.status ,
count(if(bkg.StartDate between '2018-09-17' and '2018-10-17',bkg.status,0)) as 'sep',
count(if(bkg.StartDate between '2018-10-17' and '2018-11-17',bkg.status,0)) as 'Oct'
from tbl_booking bkg 
group by bkg.status
```

But this is giving me Results like

[image]

If I remove Group by, it gives e results

, I also tried

```
  SELECT bkg.status,
        count(CASE WHEN bkg.StartDate between '2018-09-17' and '2018-10-17' THEN bkg.status ELSE 0 END) AS 'sep',
        count(CASE WHEN bkg.StartDate between '2018-10-17' and '2018-11-17' THEN bkg.status ELSE 0 END) AS 'Oct'
    FROM tbl_booking bkg
GROUP BY bkg.status
```

Bit result seems to be same .
[image]

for a date between '2018-10-17' and '2018-11-17', there is no record, so it should return 0, but it gives me all count value same for all months.

please suggest what I can modify more in my query

Comment: No pictures, thanks. Instead, see: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query). That said, seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: ok,I am removing pics

Comment: `count(if(bkg.StartDate between '2018-09-17' and '2018-10-17',bkg.status,0))` . In this, even when your if condition fails, you are returning 0. Now, `COUNT(0)` will still count this as one row. You need to return `NULL` when condition is false. It should be like this: `count(if(bkg.StartDate between '2018-09-17' and '2018-10-17',bkg.status,NULL))`
This is one basic mistake in your case; there may be other mistakes as well. I have not fully analyzed it

Comment: yes , else part was the concern .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the else part as you are using count so when you put else 0 it is counting it, if you use sum then it is ok but for count you can skip the else so it consider other value as null and give you exact count

```
SELECT bkg.status,
        count(CASE WHEN bkg.StartDate between '2018-09-17' and '2018-10-17' THEN bkg.status END) AS 'sep',
        count(CASE WHEN bkg.StartDate between '2018-10-17' and '2018-11-17' THEN bkg.status END) AS 'Oct'
    FROM tbl_booking bkg 
GROUP BY bkg.status
```

Comment: yes , else part was the culprit , that was my main concern why it counting null values .. thanks .I am doing small testing  . then will accept this answer :)

Answer (score 0):

`count(if(bkg.StartDate between '2018-09-17' and '2018-10-17',bkg.status,0))`

In the above code of yours, even when your `IF` condition fails, you are returning **0**. Now, `COUNT(0` will still count this as one row, hence you get same row count.

You need to return `NULL` when **condition is false**. It should be like this:

`count(if(bkg.StartDate between '2018-09-17' and '2018-10-17',bkg.status,NULL))`

This will not count the row, if the condition fails.

Following is the revised overall query:

```
SELECT bkg.StartDate ,bkg.status ,
count(if(bkg.StartDate between '2018-09-17' and '2018-10-17',bkg.status,NULL)) as 'sep',
count(if(bkg.StartDate between '2018-10-17' and '2018-11-17',bkg.status,NULL)) as 'Oct'
from tbl_booking bkg 
group by bkg.status
```